# How does USB FAT32 copy files?

Tags: usb

I was copying files between two flash drives, both Mosdart 32GB drives, when it occurred to me a possible that file transfer with USB drives works. Just about any time I copy large directories full of files between USB drives, I notice a distinctive wave pattern in the copy speed:

[image]

This led me to believe that either USB or FAT32 has a buffer which fills up and must be emptied. I suspect that the data transfer speed rises after the buffer is emptied, then drops out when it is filled. After that, it repeats.

Is this a design of USB or of FAT32? Is this actually a buffer causing this?

Comment: Not really a programming question. Also a filesystem by itself can’t have a buffer and USB is also just a protocol. The operating system does many things though.